# How to select * in linq while using join

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

This is the sql query. The results of both query should be same, but it is not same.

```
select * from Product pjoin TierImageMap ti on ti.ProductId=p.Idjoin Tiers t on t.Id=ti.TierType where p.Id=1AND ti.ImageVersion=2
```

This is the equivalent linq query i wrote but the answers are not similar.The results of the sql query is not same .

```
(from p in _context.Product
join ti in _context.TierImageMap on p.Id equals ti.ProductId
join t in _context.Tiers on ti.TierType equals t.Id
where (p.Id == productid) && (ti.ImageVersion==imageversion)
select new
 {
   t,ti,p
  }).ToList().Distinct();
```

Comment: As your sql says `select * from Product` you should just do `select p` in linq

Comment: Im afraid you cannot  select all columns including join table columns .You need to manually add all the column when selecting 
i.e 

`select new
 {
   t.col1,
   t.col2,...
   ti.col1,
   ti.col2,..
    p.col1,
    p.col2, ...
  }`